wal_init_zero in PostgreSQL

In the original CL here, author mentioned a discussion linked here. However, this discussion seems to focus mainly on the allowance for disabling WAL recycling. Is this the correct discussion, or is there another one that directly addresses wal_init_zero?

Why don’t we use fallocate for filling up with zeros? fallocate seems like it would accomplish the same thing but more efficiently.

We've been doing some performance benchmarking and noticed that at a high WAL rate (e.g., 96 vCPUs with 700 concurrent workers), wal_init_zero is causing significant latency, leading to performance regression. Does anyone have any insights or suggestions regarding this?


I would like to understand wal_init_zero in depth and for that I would like to know why was it introduced at first place. Also, for what all file systems we don't really need it? The official document mentions that for COW file systems we might not benefit from wal_init_zero but the description is very brief. Can someone please guide me here?
I'm quite new to file system and databases.

Can you point us to the point in the code where you think fallocate should be used? And are you talking about the Linux only syscall, or to posix_fallocate?

If you know little about file systems and databases, my answer may not satisfy. But it is not possible to provide all that knowledge in a single answer.
Both parameters were introduced for the sole benefit of ZFS. You want to disable them both on ZFS. It could have been a single parameter that governs both aspects, but as the commit message details, there might be some use for only one of them, although it is not entirely clear what that use may be.
Perhaps the linked thread offers some insight; I didn't bother reading through it.
